# Using client certificate instead of client secret to authenticate against DataLake Gen2 from Azure Databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-data-lake, azure-databricks

I am following the documentation shared here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-datalake-gen2#adls2-aad-credentials to mount my datalake account using Service principal. While the documentation mentions the steps to do this using Azure AD App's client secret. I could not find a way to use a client certificate instead. Is service principal auth using certificate credentials supported for this flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, it is not supported to mount the Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 account via the client certificate currently.

If you have such a requirement, you could post it in the [Azure Databricks feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/909463-azure-databricks).

Comment: Still not supported?